# Operating system on separate discs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10 and have the option of choosing between two OS while system boots. The tricky part is that I am using second hard drive as data storage for Windows.

I have first SSD disk with Windows bootloader, OS, recovery and stuff.

The second hdd drive as I mentioned is a data storage.

What I stopped with:

- Secure boot disabled.
- Formatted hdd disk to provied 250 GB for Linux.
- Partitioned free space as follows:

  - 512 for boot loader of linux
  - 1Gb for /boot
  - 35 Gb for root
  - 8 Gb for swap
  - The rest space I allocated for /home
- Changed booting sequence (disk with ubunu activates first)

This configuration provides me the option to choose either of the two OS, but when I choose Ubuntu, it causes an error and puts me in intramfs.
[My Disk Partition Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRfYi.png)

I will be really thankfull for any kind of advice or tip in this matter.

Comment: When you reach 'initramfs', if you can, provide the output of ```cat /proc/cmdline``` as well as ```ls /dev```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, i once more performed all steps which i mentioned in question and it works. The only one difference is that i've used Rufus to establish my ISO USB, before i've used really out-of-date software. In that case i will close issue. Once more thanks 4 ur time and sorry for problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what i've mentioned in question just simply follow provided steps and during establishing of ISO USB use "**Rufus**" software. Everything works perfectly fine.
I have two separate OS'es on two separate discs, where second disc is partially used by windows os.